# Why is this an invalid smali register?

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, smali, apktool

I injected this piece of code `invoke-static {p0}, Lcom/outfit7/talkingtomcandyrun/Toast;->show(Landroid/content/Context;)V` in a decompiled app.

Like this:

```
.line 70
    move-object/from16 v0, p0

    iget-object v0, v0, Lcom/bee7/gamewall/dialogs/BannerNotificationDialog;->sharedPreferencesNotificationsHelper:Lcom/bee7/sdk/common/util/SharedPreferencesNotificationsHelper;

    move-object/from16 v21, v0

    sget v22, Lcom/bee7/gamewall/BannerNotification;->NUMBER_OF_REWARD_BANNER_NOTIFICATIONS_LAYOUTS:I

    invoke-virtual/range {v21 .. v22}, Lcom/bee7/sdk/common/util/SharedPreferencesNotificationsHelper;->getNextRewardNotificationLayout(I)I

    .line 76
    sget v21, Lcom/bee7/gamewall/R$layout;->gamewall_banner_notification_reward_0:I

    move-object/from16 v0, p0

    move/from16 v1, v21

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/bee7/gamewall/dialogs/BannerNotificationDialog;->setContentView(I)V     
    invoke-static {p0}, Lcom/outfit7/talkingtomcandyrun/Toast;->show(Landroid/content/Context;)V

    .line 77
    const/16 v21, 0x1

    move/from16 v0, v21

    move-object/from16 v1, p0

    iput v0, v1, Lcom/bee7/gamewall/dialogs/BannerNotificationDialog;->numberOfOffersInBannerNotification:I
```

But when i tried to build it with apktool i rechieve the following message:

`com.outfit7.talkingtomcandyrun\smali\com\bee7\gamewall\dialogs\BannerNotificationDialog.smali[179,106] Invalid register: v25. Must be between v0 and v15, inclusive.`

Referring to this line: `invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/bee7/gamewall/dialogs/BannerNotificationDialog;->setContentView(I)V`.

Why am i getting this error? I don't even see register `v25` in the code.

**Edit:**

I tried it with some other apps and noticed that the error always adds 1 to the highest register. So if the highest register in the method is `v17` it will say `Invalid register: v18`.

Comment: It works fine in other apps i decompiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the `invoke-static` opcode, you'll see that it uses 4 bits to encode each parameter register, which only allows it to reference registers 0-15.

`p0` is a parameter register, and the parameter registers are at the end of the "allocated" register range in the method.

So, if the method has, say, 30 registers (`.registers 30`), and it has 5 (non-long/non-double) arguments, then the arguments to the method will be passed in as v25-v29. The `pNN` registers are just an alias to this range of registers at the end. So in this case, `p0` is an alias for `v25`. `p1` is an alias for `v26`, etc.

Also, when counting up the number of arguments, don't forget to include the implicit `this` argument for non-static methods, which is always the first passed argument. i.e. `p0`

In this case, your best bet is to use invoke-static/range instead, which accepts a contiguous range of registers, and can directly reference these higher registers.

e.g.

```
invoke-static/range {p0}, Lcom/outfit7/talkingtomcandyrun/Toast;->show(Landroid/content/Context;)V`
```

Another option would be to use `move-object` to swap the value in `p0` with a lower register temporarily, and then swap it back afterward. You'll need to find or create an unused register in order to do the swap, of course.

Comment: It seems to me that `move-object` might not work in this case. At least it didn't for me. It's supposed to be using the `move-object/16` version

Comment: The only difference between move-object and move-object/16 is move-object is limited to v0-v255 for the source register. move-object/16 can reference the whole v0-v65535 range. It's assumed that you would choose the correct move-object variant for your needs.

Comment: Hmmm, that's curious because in my case p0 was a v18 register so the app wasn't compiling when I was using a simple `move-object`. But from your answer I understood that it should have been working fine with a non /16 version?

Comment: There's really not enough context here to answer your question. I would recommend creating an actual question, with the full context of your specific situation.